# Aligning text using TextBlock.Inlines for WPF/Windows Phone

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am using TextBlock.Inlines to programmatically set text properties in the "Behind Code" in my windows Phone app.
 Does anyone know how to programmatically align the text using inlines?
 I've tried the applying the alignment property as depicted below without much luck.

```
 MyLabel.Inlines.Add(new Run() { Text = "My Text  ", FontSize = 10, VerticalAlignment = new ( VerticalAlignment.Center) });
```

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "align the text"? Align it to something? Center it?

Comment: You should just write `VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center`, without `new()` operator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you really sure you want to use vertical alignment? You most probably want to use horizontal one instead. Maybe this will fix your problem.